# Ruby gem or snippet to find full CSS path of anchor tag

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to achieve the following: I would like to find a ruby gem or function which given a link(or more generally an element on the page) on a page can return me the CSS path of that link (or more generally of that element).
That would be the equivalent of "Copy CSS path" in Google Chrome, but in a Ruby environment.

For example, if you take: www.google.com, the RoR function/gem for the first anchor tag should return: `#gbw > div > div > div.gb_Wd.gb_R.gb_be.gb_4d.gb_U > div:nth-child(1) > a`

Any way to achieve this in RoR?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**Nokogiri**](http://www.nokogiri.org/) can do this. It's an advanced XML/HTML parser for ruby.

You simply select a node, like you do it in Chromes Developer Tool and get the css path from it by using the [`css_path()`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri%2FXML%2FNode%3Acss_path) method.

```
html_doc = Nokogiri::HTML("<html><body><h1>Hello Stackoverflow</h1></body></html>")
html_doc.xpath("//body").first.css_path
```

Comment: Works very well, the only tiny issue is that it returns the elements by it's "nth-of-type" number in the CSS path rather than by its id or class name which would be better in my case. So the path I get is html>body>div:nth-of-type(1)>a, rather than html>body>div.someclass>a .I guess I could work around that issue though. Thanks Robin for the heads up!